# Wordpress End If Statements

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Apologies, PHP is not my strongest area so this might seem super easy to others.

I am trying to implement a statement to say, when there is something in my WooCommerce Cart to show the cart. If there's nothing in the cart then show nothing.

The code I have so far is:

```
<?php if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) == 0 ) {
  // The cart is empty
} else {

<div class="header-cart-inner">
  <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count ), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
</div>

} ?>
```

The code doesn't work and keeps giving me syntax errors.

Comment: what kind of syntax error

Comment: It's clear in this case, but if you can get into the habit of pasting in the exact errors you get (message, line number, whether it is a notice/warning/fatal etc) that can really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) == 0 ) {
  // The cart is empty
} else { ?>

<div class="header-cart-inner">
  <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count ), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

That should do!

Explanation :
All PHP code is going between `<?php` #php code# `?>` everything between these two tags is going to be compiled by the PHP engine. You didn't close your PHP after `else {` because of this your next piece of script `<div clas...` is going to be interpreted as PHP code. Now the PHP engine is going to read this and doesn't know what to make of it since it's not PHP and will throw an error.

Comment: Thank you this is great! I wish I had realised earlier that I have my statements the wrong way round. Annoying the code won't work in the top statement. Thanks for your help though :-)

Answer (score 0):

First-of-all you need to use "woocommerce_check_cart_items" hook to check cart item. And also you didn't close the php tag before starting to the HTML.

Here is an example :

```
<?php
function E_Coding_Hub_Coder() {

    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
        wc_print_notice( __( '(E-Coding Hub Message) Your Cart is Empty', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice');
    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="header-cart-inner">
            <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count ), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
       </div>
       <?php
    } 
}

// Add to cart page
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'E_Coding_Hub_Coder' );

// Add to shop archives & product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'E_Coding_Hub_Coder' );
```